# What's the right way of using 'typedef'?

Tags: c, typedef

I was writing the code in this way first

```
typedef struct 
{   
    struct Node *next;
    int data;
} Node;
```

because I learned that I can write `struct` without writing `Node` next to `struct` like this (if I use `typedef`)

```
typedef struct Node
{   
    struct Node *next;
    int data;
} Node;
```

But if I write without `Node`, later the warnings would appear when I'm using codes like `Node *cur = head->next`

The warning sign is:

> 'warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'Node *' with an expression of type 'struct Node *''

(FYI I use mac os and visual studio code)

I know how to fix this but I don't know why in some compilers the prior code works and in some others it doesn't work.

And what is the best way to define `struct`? Is using `typedef` recommended?

Comment: Both create the `typedef` of the struct to `Node`, but in the first case, the struct itself has no tag, while in the second it has the tag `Node` as well. Stuct tag space and typedefs do not conflict. In the second case you can use either `Node` or `struct Node` to refer to the struct, in the first you are limited to referring to the type as `Node` only. To declare a pointer, you must have a type first. The second case is equivalent to `struct Node { struct Node *next; int data; }; typedef struct Node Node;` By using the tag you create a forward reference to `struct Node`

Comment: by "some compilers" you probably mean "some compilers for a different language"

Comment: In the first case `typedef struct` does not provide any information for `struct Node *next;`

Comment: _I don't know why in some compilers the prior code works_  can you please let us know what are those compilers, so that we can try.

Comment: I am listening to a lecture that was uploaded years ago and the teacher uses Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 15.7.4 ver. In his lecture, the compiler for C language works fine with that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the structure definition, the name of the structure (`struct Node`) is visible, but the typedef (`Node`) isn't. Your first example doesn't give any name to the structure you're defining, only one to the typedef, and so the declaration of the `next` field in the structure definition is forward-declaring a new structure called `struct Node`, which is different from the anonymous structure you declared that's typedefed as `Node`.